# Странное поведение rfind()

Tags: c++, строки, поиск, анализ

Дано:

```
std::string s = "issip";
std::string sstr = "p";
int r = 3;
```

Есть условие:

```
size_t nsub = std::string::npos;
if((nsub = s.rfind(sstr, r)) == std::string::npos)
```

Вопрос: 

Почему условие выполняется, хотя подстрока `"p"` входит в строку `"ip"`

> i - 0 
>  s - 1 
> s - 2 
> **i - 3**
>  **p - 4**

в позиции `4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rfind` выполняет поиск с конца строки, либо с индекса, который передали (а точнее индекс минус размер переданной строки), и идёт в начало строки (при этом ищет нужную строку справа от текущей позиции).

А так как поиск начинается с символа с индексом 3, а "p" находится на 4, то начиная с индекса 3 и идя в начало строки, `rfind` не находит больше `"p"` и выдаёт `npos`