# Непонятное поведение rfind()

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, c++11

Дано:

```
std::string s = "GCAGAGAG"
string sstr = s.substr(7); // = "G"
```

Выполняю [**`rfind()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/):

```
auto nsub = s.rfind(sstr, 6);
```

Получаю

```
nsub равен 5
```

**Вопрос: почему так?**

По логике, мы имеем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если верить [**@Drawn Raccoon**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089955/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-rfind), получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ответ должен быть или **`0`** или **`7`**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак,

```
std::string s = "GCAGAGAG"
string sstr = s.substr(7); // = "G"
```

Пока да.

```
auto nsub = s.rfind(sstr, 6);
```

В строке

```
"GCAGAGAG"
```

мы ищем `G`, начиная с 6 позиции и идя к началу строки. И видим такую букву в позиции 5...

```
GCAGAGAG
01234567
     ^
```

Что не так?...

Грубо говоря, `rfind` работает так: Ага, нам передано 6. Что у нас в `s[6]`? `A` - не подходит... Далее, `6-1=5`. Что у нас в `s[5]`? `G`? Отлично, что искали, вернуть 5...

Comment: То, что предыдущий человек объяснил мне не так :)

Comment: Это объяснение вас устраивает? :)

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Спустя три минуты отмечу ответом

Comment: Да главное, чтоб было понятно :) "Главное, чтобы костюмчик сидел..."

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение у ответу выше.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо, **@Harry**